# Is it ok if yodlee user get register through app?

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, yodlee

We are building a finance app and integration Yodlee in it and we have come to situation where we need user's loging.

Now we have two scenarion,

1. Ask user to login & use token for API call. But as userSessionToken expires after every 30 minutes, we need to open yodlee login screen.
2. We can register yodlee user when any user sign-up on our site and use his credential from back-end to get yodlee userSessionToken

Scenario 2 has data protecting issue. Is there any way where we can get new token with a single user login.

Please suggest me if there is any alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

You should use second approach, as you don't want user to register twice.
Once user registers to your site you should internally call register3 API to register that user with Yodlee. There is no data protecting issue, unless you don't have required security standards in place.

Comment: With scenario 2, application would have to store raw user passwords, to be able to login them to Yodlee. This is really a security issue. Are there any alternatives to that approach?

Comment: @IvanVirabyan you don't have to store raw user passwords. You are going to store user's credentials when they register with your app, similarly you can store(or reuse) the credentials with which you are registering the user to Yodlee.